# Asynchronous Client Socket Example from MSDN

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, msdn

Ive a question about this example: [Asynchronous Client Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) .
It says that the operations are asynchronous and they **ARE** (beginxxx/endxxx are presented), but they use `ManualResetEvent` and if i understand the sample code correctly - such calls:

```
  Receive(client);
  receiveDone.WaitOne();
```

Will block the thread, they were called from. So that if i have an application with UI and i call that async socket code from main thread - application will freeze...Or am i wrong? Sorry, i expected to send/receive some commands over tcp asynchronously without freezing main thread. Will i have to call all the socket operations from that sample to avoid freezing?

Comment: The example is for a Console application. I think it would make more sense in a GUI application because you could have the Receive callback draw updates to the view and the Send function is only called on a button click (or some other event). The only reason to block in this example is to ensure linear events of connect, send, receive, close and also prevent the program from exiting before the callbacks complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code is set up so that it will run synchronously. However, you can easily use the Beginxxx and Endxxx calls yourself rather than wrapping them as this (poor) example of asynchronous action is written.

For further clarification, the article does run each method asynchronously, but then blocks using `blocker.WaitOne();` A better approach to something like this might be to have your beginconnect callback trigger a send, which will have its callback trigger a receive, etc

You could also use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and take advantage of their [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) functionality to do this. Then your code might even look cleaner :)

Comment: @0x49D1 Often that is correct, but as with everything in life, you should never agree with something just because it comes from a particular place (and you didnt, which is good :)). Also, often MSDN articles are written by outsiders (I do not see that here), so it is not always direct from Redmond

Answer (score 1):

It would block the UI. The MSDN example does demonstrate asynchronousy, but very poorly. Its also primitive. Please look at this topic which I also just answered regarding different asynchronous programming models. I discuss quite a few and provide links for all of them with full examples.

Link: [Need help to implement multithreading in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224060/need-help-to-implement-multithreading-in-c-sharp/10224391#10224391)

Comment: Thank you, guys for the answers..I was afraid that ive asked some stupid thing and it turns out that i understood it correctly. @David Anderson , thank you for examples!